# Android app background resources loading 1/4 resolution and scaling pixelated

Tags: java, android

First question here, but I have done extensive searching on this particular issue and seem to be unable to get the right keywords or something... because I can't see anyone else having this problem.

I'm working to complete an Android app port that someone else built using resources from a corresponding retina iPad app. We are having some issues with the garbage collector, and I anticipate that part of this is due to the extra-large resources (2048x1536) being loaded as backgrounds.

The app is really only for tablets, therefore, I scaled the backgrounds down in Photoshop to a smaller 1280x752 (native test tablet's resolution is 1280x800). However, when they are loaded in the app, they look like they were loaded as 640x326 images and then upsized - so they are blurry/pixelated even though they are native resolutions for the screen.

What can I do to keep these images loading properly without totally blasting the memory with images that are 4x the size I need?

======

Here is the relevant info in the manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="12" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Here is a snippet of a LinearLayout XML where one of these backgrounds is loaded:

```
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/edit_background"
android:weightSum="1.0"
```

I have tried putting the resources in different drawable folders just to confirm, and I have disabled all but `xlarge` screens in the support-screens section of the manifest... and nothing is helping.

I can't find anything.

Comment: have you tried removing the background from the view and use windowBackground instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, using windowBackground produces the same pixelated/fuzzy downsized-then-upscaled result.

Comment: Put them in res/drawable-nodpi

Comment: FYI: The supports-screens element is only used by Google Play when determining device compatibility. It has no effect on a device running your app.

Answer (score 0):

Simon was correct: res/drawable-nodpi did the trick